# Does opening a crash dump run a file in memory?

Tags: ida, malware, windbg, memory-dump

I am new to malware analysis, and I'm learning how to detect malware that uses process injection to execute PE files from memory. I chose a ransomware sample that uses process injection to load the actual payload in memory and took a crash dump at the point where the executable is loaded into memory. Is it safe to open (and not run) the crash dump file in WinDbg in a trusted environment? I will be using WinDbg commands to list peb, TIDs etc.

Answer (score 1):

In short, yes it is safe. The debuggers won't map crash dumps into executable memory, and extensions such as `.call` only work in live debugging.